# How can I find the documentation for AJAX on Rails in the DocRails repo on Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation

I found some things I want to submit a pull request for in the [AJAX documentation for rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html).

But when I check out the [DocRails repo](https://github.com/lifo/docrails), I can't seem to find that documentation.

Anyone familiar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the guides folder?

https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/guides/source/ajax_on_rails.textile

Comment: Thanks. I looked there, but never went into the 'source' subfolder. Checked the 'assets' and 'rails_guides' and left.